# Import users once a day without a plugin

Tags: users, import, csv

<strike>I need to import users to my WP database once a day.
So I have a script that runs once a day to do an action.
The problem that I'm having is that I'm a little over my head on this one.</strike>

Another company provides me with userdata in a .csv file.
I then need to import this file to my WP database.

The script I use for running once a day is the following (this is in my functions.php):

```
add_action( 'wp', 'prefix_setup_schedule' );
/**
* On an early action hook, check if the hook is scheduled - if not, schedule it.
*/
function prefix_setup_schedule() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'prefix_hourly_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'prefix_hourly_event');
    }
}


add_action( 'prefix_hourly_event', 'prefix_do_this_hourly' );
/**
* On the scheduled action hook, run a function.
*/
function prefix_do_this_hourly() {
    wp_mail( 'user@domain.com', 'Automatic email sent at '.time(), 'Automatic scheduled email from WordPress.');
}
```

On the server runs a cronjob that activates `wp-cron.php` once a day. If there aren't any users the script won't run so I activate it. Once there is activity it runs.

This is a simple working example of an email that is sent every hour.
Now I need to import users.

Here is what I found:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/file/users.csv'
INTO TABLE discounts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I don't know if this works I'm not there yet. The problem I'm facing now it that the usersystem of WordPres exists of two tables `wp_user` and `wp_usermeta`.

Can anybody tell me if I'm even on the right track and how to solve this. Is there maybe a way to seperate the .csv file and select what to import where including the fact that there is a refference between the `user` and `usermeta` tables?

M.

I changed my way of thinking and want to do the following:

```
$row = 1;
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
if (($handle = fopen(get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/import_test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

This is a direct copy from http://php.net/fgetcsv. 
Now I want to replace the for loop with an `wp_create_user` function to add the user.
At the same time I need to add user_meta to that user (I think).
Any ideas how I can add a user with metafields and select the right values from my csv file matching the `vars`?

- EDIT -
  I have come so far but I can't get the last part to work.
  I have the adding of a new user fixed. 
  The foreach loops through the csv to add all users:

  ```
  $filepath = get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/import_test.csv";
  ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
  $file = fopen($filepath, "r") or die("Error opening file");
  $i = 0;

  while(($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
      if($i == 0) {
      $c = 0;
      foreach($line as $col) {
          $cols[$c] = $col;
          $c++;
      }
  } else if($i > 0) {
  $c = 0;
      foreach($line as $col) {
          $data[$i][$cols[$c]] = $col;
          $c++;
      }
  }
  $i++;
  ```

  }

  ```
  foreach ($data as $gebruiker){
      $username = $gebruiker['username'];
      if ( username_exists( $username ) ){
          $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username);
          update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'meta_key', $gebruiker['email'] );
      }
      else{
          $users = wp_insert_user(
              array(
              'user_login'    =>  $gebruiker['username'],
              'user_pass'     =>  $gebruiker['password'],
              'first_name'    =>  $gebruiker['first_name'],
              'last_name'     =>  $gebruiker['last_name'],
              'user_email'    =>  $gebruiker['email'],
              'display_name'  =>  $gebruiker['first_name'] . ' ' . $gebruiker['last_name'],
              'nickname'      =>  $gebruiker['first_name'] . '' . $gebruiker['last_name'],
              'role'          =>  'subscriber'
              )                       
          );
          foreach ($data as $update_user) {   
              update_user_meta( $users, 'import_1', $update_user['first_name'] );
              update_user_meta( $users, 'import_2', $update_user['last_name'] );
          }
      }
  }
  ```

To add files to the `wp_usermeta` table I want to work with `update_user_meta` since the `wp_insert_user` comes back with an ID of the just created user.

But no matter where I place the `update_user_meta` in the loop it gives me back the following error: 
`Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in`
The error is fixed. Because the users allready existed. So need to check for that later. This does mean that the fields are added to the usermeta but empty

====== EDIT ======
The above code is final and working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [wp_create_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) and pass necessary  information like `$username, $password, $email` , where `$email` is optional.

If user created successfully it will return `ID` of newly created user, other wise will return error object.

Then update user's other information using [update_user_meta.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)

Comment: Wow that was exactly what I was reading here:https://tommcfarlin.com/add-custom-user-meta-during-registration/ I'll give it a try

Comment: Please see my edit. I'm so close but can't finish

Comment: your `$user` will be user id if created successfully. Then use `update_user_meta`.

Comment: I got it working now. See my updated code... Thnx for your help

Comment: Happy to help you, welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of CSV importer/exporter libraries to extract the CSV file data and save them as user details. FYI - always use wordpress functions to save anything. for ex. `update_user_meta` etc.

Cron you are using is correct and should run properly.

Library for extracting CSV data : [goodby](https://github.com/goodby/csv)

EDIT:

try adding a error handling in your code:

`//On success 
if( !is_wp_error($user) ) {
 echo "User created : ". $user; // update your meta here
}`

Comment: Thank you for your feed back. CronJob runs fine. I was hoping I could do this without a external Library. However I will take a look at it. I like the idea however to save data with the WP-functions instead of directly putting them in the database

Comment: I can't make anything of the library. But that is probably my problem because my knowledge doesn't reach there. can't I just import the data into fields and save them without the use of a button?

Comment: Yes. You can import the data into fields and save them with help of cron. Just make a cron script that will fetch the data from the csv file and save them accordingly. But for the same you have to use the csv library.

Comment: see this answers here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2805442/1576040. you can make use of php functions to extract csv data

Comment: Please read my edit so you know where I'm at right now!